# Does the iPad Smart Connector have charging functionality?

Tags: ipad, charging, accessories, smart-keyboard

In the comments under an answer on another question, a user commented that the Smart Connector on an iPad (7th generation) is

> "not a charging system"

and that

> "the [Apple Smart] keyboard doesn't charge by the smart connector. The
> keyboard is changed by the usb-c port. The iPad is charged via the
> usb-c port and pass-through charging thru the smart connector."

However, [at least one (non-Apple) keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/ipad-keyboards/rugged-folio.920-009312.html) appears to both pair *and* charge via the Smart Connector:

> Rugged Folio for iPad (7th and 8th generation) is a slim keyboard case
> with drop protection that exceeds military standard tests. **It uses
> Smart Connector technology so no pairing or charging is required.** High
> performance spill and dirt-resistant sealed keys make this the perfect
> tool for on-the-go work. Enjoy a full-size keyboard with convenient
> iOS® shortcut keys, front and back protection for your iPad, and a
> convenient spot to stow Logitech Crayon or Apple Pencil® (1st gen).

(Emphasis added.)

So my questions:

1. Does either the [Smart Keyboard Folio or Smart Keyboard](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205237) charge via the Smart Connector?  Is the answer different on the 7th generation and 8th generation iPads?
2. If the answer to 1 is "Yes", does the 8th generation iPad use the same connector to charge the Apple Pencil 2, or does it use a separate magnetic induction system to do that?  (Note that the 8th gen iPad **is** compatible with the Pencil 2, even though the 7th gen is not.)  If the latter, is there a reason why?  It seems weirdly redundant to build two different systems for charging accessories into the sides of the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I see Apple smart connector devices similar to wired USB keyboards and mice that run on low voltage DC and have no batteries to charge and no Bluetooth to pair, but I could be misinformed.

> Unlike Bluetooth keyboards, you don't need to pair or turn on your Smart Keyboard Folio or Smart Keyboard.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205237

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

No, the Smart Keyboard Folio and the Smart Keyboard do not *charge* via the Smart Connector. The reason being simply that these devices do not have batteries. There's nothing to charge. They are being powered by the Smart Connector though.

**Question 2:**

The answer to question 1 was no, but I'll expand on this:

The Apple Pencil 2 does not charge through the Smart Connector, nor is it powered through the Smart connector on any iPad.

When you ask about Apple's "reason why" - it's unfortunately not possible to answer by anyone but the people at Apple involved in that decision.

However, from a purely logical standpoint, there's a number of possible reasons:

1. The Smart Connector contrary to the Apple Pencil 2 charging system is not a charging system nor is it wireless.
2. As the Smart Connector is not wireless, but requires physical contact between the 3 points on the iPad and similar 3 points on the accessory, it is probably much easier to get a large keyboard with magnets embedded on the large connecting edge to position and align properly to create that physical contact between the points.
3. The Smart Connector is not only not a charger, but it is also performs a completely different function as it also transfers data. There is a 1-wire protocol embedded into it that allows the iPad and the accessory to communicate through that (instead of over some additional, wireless system).